# Animate tooltip on user hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make my tooltip bounce onmouse hover,

I have the following that works with sporadic results, as in the the tooltip bounces fast for 3 seconrds ro so, then slow for 3 seconds etc... I also need to stop this function on mouseout, Can somebody see where im going wrong to get the variation in bounce speed?

```
// Tooltip title
$('.male').mouseover(function(e) { 

    var tiptitle = $(this).find('.highlight');

    setInterval(function(){
              tiptitle.animate({top:'-85px'}, 100, function() {
              tiptitle.animate({top:'-75px'}, 100);
        });
    },200);
}).mouseout(function() {



});
```

Comment: I would recommend using jQuery UI's bounce effects see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce

Comment: Unless @Liam has other uses for jQuery UI, this is a lot of bulk to add to a page for a simple animation.

Comment: Thanks @LeighCiechanowski but I dont really want to include the entire library for such a small feature

Answer (score 0):

if you choose to go the route of the effects plugin bounce effect use this code , then use stop() on mouseout

```
$('.male').mouseover(function(e) {     
    var tiptitle = $(this).find('.highlight');    
    tiptitle.effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.highlight').stop();
 });
```

otherwise , I believe you are getting sporadic speeds of bounce because of -85px and -75px both at 100

Comment: Thanks @ScottSelby, Ive gone down this route, but if i keep mousing in and out repeatedly the tooltip gets higher and higher and higher if this makes sense?